# In Laravel how can I replace a controller/method/id with just /slug in the URL?

Tags: php, laravel, slug, laravel-routing

What is the best way I could replace /controller/method/id in the URL with just /slug?

For example: trips/1 would become /honduras-trip

This is what I am doing but couldn't their be a better way?

My routes:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', 'HomeController@show');
```

My Controller:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $class = Slug::where('name', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    if($class->slugable_type == 'Trip')
    {
        $trip = Trip::find($class->slugable_id);
        return $trip;
    }
    if($class->slugable_type == 'Project')
    {
        $project = Project::find($class->slugable_id);
        return $project;
    }
    if($class->slugable_type == 'User')
    {
        $user = User::find($class->slugable_id);
        return $user;
    }

}
```

My Slug Model:

```
class Slug extends Eloquent {

public function slugable()
    {
    return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

The other models all have this method:

```
public function slugs()
{
    return $this->morphMany('Slug', 'slugable');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your routes.php just give

```
Route::get('slug', array('uses' => 'HomeController@show'));
```

In your controller, write show() function

```
public function show() {
  return View::make('welcome');
}
```

In your view give,

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::to('slug') }}">slug</a></li>
```

Comment: This won't work because I need 'slug' to be dynamic and to load different models depending on which model the 'slug' belongs to.